# Android Json Cannot reach in array

Tags: android, arrays

I cannot reach word_en index in android.How can I reach word_en or word_tr1 ? I get post index as String with JSONObject then I need to get word_en index. Thanks.

```
{
post: [
{
word_en: "central heating",
word_tr1: "merkezi ısıtma "
},
{
word_en: "plant",
word_tr1: "bitki "
},
{
word_en: "fireplace",
word_tr1: "şömine "
},
{
word_en: "dining room",
word_tr1: "yemek odası "
},
{
word_en: "downstairs",
word_tr1: "alt kat "
},
{
word_en: "upstairs",
word_tr1: "üst kat "
},
{
word_en: "conversation",
word_tr1: "görüşme "
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`json.getJSONArray("post").get(0).getString("word_en");`

This should give an idea.